# DRF doesn't update instead create new instance in modelserializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Searched throughout SO to find the matching questions doesn't answer mine as there are only few explanations. So hoping to get an answer here.

I have a model named "testcase" with **pk** set as "testcase_name". On update operation in the serializer, instead of updating a new instance is created everytime. I suspect it is because of the pk.

serializer.py

```
class TestcaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = testcase
        lookup_field = 'testcase_name'
        fields = ("testcase_name", 'description')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print(instance)  # returns test2 instead it should be test1 which is the current instance

        # ret = super(TestcaseSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        [setattr(instance, key, value)
         for key, value in validated_data.items()]
        instance.save() 
        print(instance)# returns test2 
        return instance
```

models.py

```
class testcase(models.Model):
    testcase_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.testcase_name
```

views.py

```
class Testcaseviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = testcase.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestcaseSerializer
    lookup_field = 'testcase_name'
```

Is there any way to solve this in the serializer itself not from the views.

Comment: first deleting the instance and then updating it solved my problem